# How to correctly write this ring theoretic thing?

Tags: ring-theory, notation, terminology

Im unsure how to write this thing below in a formal way :

For an integer $n>2$

Let $F_n(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + a_{n-1} x^{n-1}.$

Also we have $x^n = 1$ and $1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1} = 0.$

This looks like a ring.

SO a few ideas of how to describe it are :

1) $F_n[x]/(x^n-1)$

2) $F_n[x]/( 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1})$

3) $F_n[x]/( (1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1}) (x^n-1) )$

4)$ F_n[x]/(x^n-1) mod (1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1})$

5) $F_n[x]/(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1}) mod (x^n-1)$

6) $F_n[x]/(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1})/(x^n-1)$

7) $F_n[x]/(x^n-1)/(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1})$

8) $[F_n[x]/(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1})]/(x^n-1)$

9) $A_n[x] = F_n[x]/(x^n-1)$

$B_n = A_n[x]/(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1})$

All of these seem either wrong , sloppy or weird.
But I ran out of inspiration.
What is the formal way to write it ?

Comment: Note that $1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1}\mid X^n-1$, so $(1+X+X^2+\cdots+X^{n-1})\supseteq (X^n-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct notation is (assuming a ring of coefficient $F$):
$$F[x]/(x^n-1, 1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})$$

Comment: Just $F[x]/(1+...+x^{n-1})$, as $x^n-1$ is already in the latter ideal.